# Can ANCOVA be used for the following model

Tags: biostatistics, ancova

Suppose I have 3 treatment groups, and I have pre- and post-treatment test results.  There are also 4 covariates which theoreticlaly can influence the post-outcome. So is it possible to find which treatment shows the better post-test results, with ANCOVA (uni or bivariate)? Or, should I use any other?

Comment: ANCOVA seems fine for this situation as long as the outcome is continuous and the assumptions of the model are met.